# Python doesn't think Emoji[1️⃣] = 1️⃣

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have an emoji (1️⃣) that you can react to. I have the bot look for a reaction being added which it runs except it doesn't think emoji = 1️⃣. It comes back "no".

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
  channel = await self.client.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
  message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
  user = await self.client.fetch_user(payload.user_id)
  emoji = payload.emoji
  if user.id != self.client.user.id:
   message_id = message.id
   if message.id == message_id:
    if emoji == "1️⃣":
     print("yes")
    else:
     print("no")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`payload.emoji` is an instance of the [`PartialEmoji`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.PartialEmoji) class, you can't compare it to a string. Try

```python
if emoji.name == "1️⃣":
```